# awk printf prints whole file into one line

Tags: awk, while-loop, printf

I am using the following awk command with printf to edit the number of flowing digits in a matrix file.

```
while read -r line; do
  awk '{ printf "%.3e ", $0}'
done < water.txt > water3.txt
```

It works fine besides, all the lines are converted into one long line, and I would like to keep the lines in the matrix.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that awk is printing the whole file *except for the first line*.

Because you're not explicitly giving awk a filename or data redirected into its stdin, it will slurp up the rest of the `< water.txt` redirection.

```bash
while read -r line; do
  awk '{ printf "%.3e ", $0}' <<<"$line"
done < water.txt > water3.txt
```

or much more simply without the shell loop

```bash
awk '{printf "%.3e ", $0}' water.txt > water3.txt
```

Comment: Dear Glenn

The reason why I tried to use the shell-loop was to get around that awk does not detect line breaks.  So your simple solution without the shell-loop, I have already tried. 
I have tried your version of the shell-loop, but it does not change the fact that all the file is still written in one line and therefore is no longer a matrix.

I have also tried incorporating a line break after awk reads the file line by line.

while read -r line; do awk '{ printf    "%.3e " , $0 , "%d %d\n" }' <<<$line ; done <  vand.txt > vand3.txt

But it does not work either. 

/svend

Comment: "awk does not detect line breaks" -- what?

Comment: You'll get higher quality answers if you improve the question. Provide sample input data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: An example could be to convert this 4X4 matrix with 22 characters for each number  
6.0134718913464900E-154   6.0134700169990685E-154  
6.0134700169990685E-154   6.0134700169990685E-154  

to this 4x4 matrix with eight characters per number
  
6.013E-154   6.013E-154  
6.013E-154   6.013E-154  
  
But the matrix is more like 1000X1000

Answer (score 0):

> all the lines are converted into one long line, and I would like to
> keep the lines in the matrix.

[`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) does not append row separator (which by default is newline) so you need to do it yourself, typical GNU `AWK` usage in this case would be

```
awk '{ printf "%.3e\n", $0}' water.txt > water3.txt
```

if you must use `<` AT ANY PRICE then you could do it following way

```
awk '{ printf "%.3e\n", $0}' < water.txt > water3.txt
```

Comment: Dear Daweo 

The reason why I tried to use the shell-loop was to get around that awk does not detect line breaks. So the simple solution without the shell-loop, I have already tried. I have tried your version, but it does not change the fact that it is no longer a matrix, now there is just a line break after each number. I have also tried incorporating a line break after awk reads the file line by line. 

while read -r line; do awk '{ printf "%.3e " , $0 , "%d %d\n" }' <<<$line ; done < vand.txt > vand3.txt 

But it does not work either. /svend